# Postgresql a nosuperuser can't access to another a nosuperuser's owner table

Tags: postgresql

I have created a nosuperuser that name is test1. I have given update, select, delete, insert options.  Also I have given grant all schema.

```
CREATE ROLE test1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '123456';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO test1;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM test1;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLES TO test1 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Later I have created an another nosuperuser that name is test2. I have given update, select, delete, insert options. I have given grant usage schema.

```
CREATE ROLE test2 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '123456';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO test2;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM test2;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON TABLES TO test2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

When I have created a table with test1. Test2 doesnt access the table. Because the table owner is test1. I want to access the table user test2. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

When you issue `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, the new privileges are only applied to newly created objects, tables in this case. You have to manually grant the privileges to tables that already exist.

So if role `test1` created a table before the default privileges for role `test2` were set, then `test1` or a superuser has to issue the following command:

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON <table> TO test2;
```

Comment: İs there another way? How should I change my code? For example test1 created a new table. Test2 cant access that table. Two users can access existing table.

Comment: There are too many table already existing in public. Later I created role. Before all roles can access tables. Because table owner is postgres. Later  role test1 is created a table so owner is test1. When the owner is test1, test2 can't access the table.